# What RAM and SSD can I buy for this motherboard P8Z77-V?

Tags: motherboard, memory, hard-disk, ssd

I have my PC and unfortunately, it’s not a new one. I have motherboard P8Z77-V LX. So, I’d like to extend or replace old RAM which’s 8GB to increase it up to 32GB at least cos I want to develop games on Unity + AR + .NET / C#. In additional l’ve my old HDD it’s 500GB Seagate ST500DM0 which’s broken & doesn’t work properly cos I was used SWAP & it has killed HDD. Well, I want to replace it by SSD. Let’s say SSD by Kingston.

My question is what RAM & SSD can I buy for this motherboard P8Z77-V?

[image: Specs of my PC]

PS: Yes, I know I have to buy GPU also, but I'm going to do it later :)

Comment: See SuperUser - [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this motherboard does not support NVMe, you will need a SATA SSD. I personally use the Crucial MX500 because it is pretty cheap where I live and also pretty fast.

For ram you probably need DDR3, which is not availible in 2x16GB. You will probably need 2 sets of 2x8 GB of ram. You can get 2 sets of G.Skills F3-12800CL10D-16GBXL ram, that will add up to 32GB. (for if you live in Belgium or the Netherlanths, you can get the lowest price at https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/300301/g-punt-skill-f3-12800cl10d-16gbxl.html)

Comment: Thank you!) I have bought SSD, but I can't buy RAM G.Skills DDR3 cos it's out of sock :( Can you suggest me any good alternative to? Thanks in advance)

Comment: You can also get the Corsair CMV16GX3M2A1600C11, although it is a bit more expensive and slower (also x2 since this is 16GB)

Answer (score 1):

for RAM *always* consult the manufacturer documentation... it's free... it's easy... *no probably needs*

google "P8Z77-V motherboard" results in

https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/P8Z77V/HelpDesk_Knowledge/

choose memory/device support and look for RAM QVL (qualified vendor list) as well as the basic user's manual.

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8Z77-V/E7074_P8Z77-V.pdf

page 2-6  *You may install 1GB, 2GB, 4GB and 8GB unbuffered and non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.*  There are 4 sockets, so at most you can have 32gb total RAM using 4x8gb DDR3 DIMMs.

the RAM QVL will list approved memory speeds and timings, such as `F3-19200CL10Q-32GBZHD`

The QVL shows `DDR3 1600` up to `DDR3 2600`.  If you buy DDR3 greater than 2600, they will typically down clock and still work to meet the motherboard which is limited to DDR3 2600 but you do take your chances in doing so.  With DDR3 being obsolete *kinda* you may only find cheaper DDR3-3200 for example, which is ok, but ideally choose something comparable to the RAM QVL.  You do not require the `GSkill` or `Corsair` make, or only those makes listed on the QVL, while they are probably the better/best out there the no-name brands on amazon or elsewhere will work.  Just go by DDR3 between 1600 and 2600 and a kit of 4x8gb dimms.  There is an SSD QVL from ASUS you can also reference as well, although any sata ssd on amazon will work.  consult the documentation and email ASUS for confirmation before buying a pcie nvme type storage device to hold a bootable operating system.